# Python to Java encryption/decryption, making sure cipher matches?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I'm looking at some common python example code which does encryption, setup like:

```
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
chunksize = 64*1024

while True:
    chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
    if len(chunk) == 0:
        break
    elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
        chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)

    outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

Trying to set up java code to decrypt output from the above, I see examples that initialize the cipher padding differently:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

or:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
```

even though all the python snippets are implemented the same way.

I would expect to use "NoPadding" in this case. Can anyone explain what the correct selection in this case is?

Thank you

Comment: Also note that there is no guarantee for read to only return less than the requested size if you're at the end of the file. Even though it is improbably you could technically end up with only 8 bytes read which would be padded and thus additional spaces end up in your encrypted plaintext. Regarding the padding choice, if can change the python side then you should instead use PKCS5 (or PKCS7 which is the same) padding on both sides. With "` `" padding you cannot differentiate between a padded plaintext and a plaintext that just happened to have spaces at the end.

Comment: @Perseids I think I understand - there are lots of python examples out there claiming to be PKCS5 or PKCS7 that are just padding with spaces. I see from spec references that are different: [http://programmerin.blogspot.com/2011/08/python-padding-with-pkcs7.html], [ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/ascii/pkcs-7.asc]

Comment: The one in the [blogspot article](http://programmerin.blogspot.de/2011/08/python-padding-with-pkcs7.html) looks fine, even though I would guess that the python crypto library should already have the routine. Additionally I would advise you to authenticate your message after encryption using [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) (encrypt-then-mac) to prevent so called [padding oracle attacks](http://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/) (see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38942/how-to-protect-against-padding-oracle-attacks ).

Answer (score 1):

The Python code is padding with spaces (`' '`), unless I misunderstand the code (not a Python guy). You will need to pad manually in your Java code and use  `"AES/CBC/NoPadding"`.